# sshd is working but refuses connection

Tags: ssh

When I try to connect to my VPS, it *sometimes* refuses connection, sometimes doesn't without changing configurations.

```
$ ssh vps -vvvv
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/**/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/**/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/**/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for vps
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to **.**.**.** [**.**.**.**] port **.
debug1: connect to address **.**.**.** port **: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host **.**.**.** port **: Connection refused
```

however, while it's not responding, `sshd` itself appears working.

```
$ service --status-all | grep ssh
 [ + ]  ssh
$ ps auxf | grep ssh
root      8368  0.0  0.0  49272   660 ?        Ss    2014   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
$ uptime
 22:33:26 up 66 days,  6:34,  6 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.24, 0.13
```

(note: these commands are not executed via ssh)

As well, other services like Apache are working and able to be accessed via HTTP.
Any ideas about what is happening?

---

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 5156 packets, 4606K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 231 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3494 packets, 693K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
$ sudo lsof -i:3843
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    8368 root    3u  IPv4 384433104      0t0  TCP *:3843 (LISTEN)
sshd    8368 root    4u  IPv6 384433106      0t0  TCP *:3843 (LISTEN)
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        368        655          0          0        107
-/+ buffers/cache:        261        762
Swap:         1024         92        931
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
$ tail -500 /var/log/auth.log | grep -i ssh
Jan 10 21:27:30 ******** sshd[8368]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jan 10 21:28:41 ******** sshd[229]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jan 10 21:28:41 ******** sshd[304]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 3843.
Jan 10 21:28:41 ******** sshd[304]: Server listening on :: port 3843.
Jan 10 21:28:43 ******** sshd[304]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jan 10 21:28:43 ******** sshd[391]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 3843.
Jan 10 21:28:43 ******** sshd[391]: Server listening on :: port 3843.
```

---

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3843/tcp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 89, in <module>
    ui = ufw.frontend.UFWFrontend(pr.dryrun)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ufw/frontend.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.backend = UFWBackendIptables(dryrun)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ufw/backend_iptables.py", line 45, in __init__
    ufw.backend.UFWBackend.__init__(self, "iptables", d, files)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ufw/backend.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.iptables_version = ufw.util.get_iptables_version(self.iptables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 644, in get_iptables_version
    (rc, out) = cmd([exe, '-V'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ufw/util.py", line 273, in cmd
    out = sp.communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 688, in communicate
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1182, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 455, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

Comment: The firewall is definitely worth checking, as rate-limiting is often enabled there.  Could you **paste into your question** the output of `iptables -L -n -v`, preferably unredacted.  You'll also need to let us know what port your ssh server is running on.

Comment: @MadHatter Added some information. One more thing to add: I have experienced that some cronjobs failed to run with fork error. This might have something to do with.

Comment: Is there anything in the system logs that correlates with the failures (either cron or ssh)?  It's possible the system's running out of memory and the OOM killer's stepping in.  I have no idea what to make of that `iptables` error; is this real virtualisation, or mere containerisation (eg, Virtuozzo)?

Comment: Are you running as root when checking whether iptables is running?

Comment: @Dayvo good catch.  Yes, ksg, you will need to run that as root.

Comment: The iptables error might also happen if you upgraded the kernel and modules, but did not reboot after doing so.

Comment: @MadHatter @Dayvo Sorry, at first I ran `iptables` not as root. Updated again. I checked `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` and maybe OOM killer is not doing bad..

Comment: `sshd` has bound to port 3843, is that the port you are connecting to? (The `ssh` output is too obfuscated to tell)

Comment: @ThomasStinner Tried rebooting, but no effect.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yes, as the fact the connection is sometimes successful suggests.

Comment: @ksg Where does sshd log to? Is there anything at all sshd-related in the logs during the failed attempts?

Comment: @ksg Ok, good to know. Also, I would say that as we don't yet know what the factor is that changes the behavior I don't think it's necessarily helpful to make a lot of assumptions. (It could have been "oops, it's when I run my ssh command as a different user" or whatever.)

Comment: @JennyD There's nothing strange in `/var/log/auth.log` nor `/var/log/syslog` AFAIS.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Yes, you're right. I also tried `ssh **@**.**.**.** -p 3843`, with no success.

Comment: Additionally I found that connecting to localhost on the server was successful, so the problem is maybe around networking, I guess

Comment: @ksg But is that where sshd logs to, or is it logging to some other place?

Comment: Did you check your ssh config files (in /etc/ssh/) ? Do you always connect via the same public IP ? What is the frequency of failure ?

Answer (score 1):

Might be something related to the upstream service provider?

Do a NMAP to see if the port is opened or filtered, this should be telling you if it the port is being firewalled or not.

You can also do a sniffing to see how the traffic is behaving.

Comment: `nmap` says `3843/tcp closed unknown`. maybe this is the problem, but I couldn't open the port (see the added lines in the question).

Answer (score 0):

The "sometimes" aspect suggests to me a routing problem. I'd take a `tcpdump` on the server and client interfaces, also look at the `ip route` along the way.